# IBM i series (AS400 / DB2) connection issue in .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to connect iSeries DB2 AS400 database using C# .Net core 3.1.
I'm using visual studio 2019 and have added IBM.Data.DB2.Core(3.1.0.400) nuget package to my console project.
I have IBM data server driver package 11.5.4 and IBM iAccess Client solution and IBM data server client 11.5.4 installed.
Upon installing IBM data server client I got the below error but system continued installing
image.png

Below is the code where I am trying to connect to my database
String connectionStr = “Server=serverIP:50000;Database=mydatabase;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword”;
DB2Connection con1 = new DB2Connection(connectionStr);
con1.Open();

opening the connection throws an exception :
$exception {“ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: “TCP/IP”. Communication API being used: “SOCKETS”. Location where the error was detected: “xxx.xxx.xx.xx”. Communication function detecting the error: “connect”. Protocol specific error code(s): “10060”, “", "”. SQLSTATE=08001\r\n”} IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception

and if change port number to 446 then I end up getting licensing error as below
$exception {“ERROR [42968] [IBM] SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968\r\n”} IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception

Could someone please help me connecting to iSeries database using .net ?

Please let me know if I need to provide any more details to make the explanation better.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the correct port (446). For the licensing error, __either__ add the Db2 connect personal license to the clidriver license directory, __OR__ switch to using the odbc option of the IBM i access product (instead of using the odbc from data server client as that requires a license file).